# Send hexadecimal data with TCP Sockets in Node.JS

Tags: node.js, sockets, tcp, client

I'm new in Node.JS programming and want to send this data to a server using TCP Sockets

0x1 (my message class)
0x009 (my message type)
2.1. (my version)
0x00 (null)

i want to send it in one request
is it possible ?
should i use a buffer ?

it could be great if someone show how to do it

Comment: do you want more details guys ?

Comment: please someone help

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you done a thorough search with your favorite search engine?

Comment: @creimers idi, that's why i made this post. I want to send my hexadecimal values in one request following shoutcast protocol http://wiki.shoutcast.com/wiki/SHOUTcast_2_(Ultravox_2.1)_Protocol_Details

Answer (score -2):

you do not need to convert the data to Hex as far I know. Node does that authomatically

Comment: here is the more explanation -https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/174392/Sending-Hex-over-TCP